# Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding when upload file to Rails api only server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rackattack, rack-cors

I am working on web app that use `Reactjs` as a front-end and `Rails5 api only` app as a back-end

This is the data that i send to the server as `Request payload`

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCD1o71UpVNpU4v86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[username]"

oeuoeoaeaoe
------WebKitFormBoundaryCD1o71UpVNpU4v86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[profile_image]"; filename="gggg.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryCD1o71UpVNpU4v86--
```

This is my controller

```
def update_with_image
    user = current_user
    if user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      render json: user, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end


  private

  def user_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username,:profile_image)
  end
```

So when i tried to upload image to Rails server i got this error

```
ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding ("user[username]"

oeuoeoaeaoe
------WebKitFormBoundaryCD1o71UpVNpU4v86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[profile_image]"; filename="gggg.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

????JFIF????@6"??

??F!1AQ "aq?
#2???B?????$3Rb?%Cr??????       ??A!1A"Qaq?2???BR???#b??3rS?$Cs????
                                                                   ??%)):

rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:72:in `rescue in parse_nested_query'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:61:in `parse_nested_query'
```

** I use  `Rack::Cors` and `Rack::Attack` as my middileware

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your post Headers 'Content-Type'

Comment: I am facing similar issue with ``ionic`` image upload. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @aston For this problem i already to use image base 64 instead.

Comment: @raj nope i have to encode my image to base64 and send it to server instead

Comment: my issue got resolved after turning off chunedMode

Answer (score 5):

Wasted one day on this problem.

A correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812593/11792577

Don't set `Content-Type` header when you use fetch to post `multipart/form-data` to Rails api server.

**WRONG**

```js
// this is not working
fetch(
  url,
  {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    /*
    * or
    * headers: {
    *   'Content-Type': '',
    *   'Content-Type': undefined,
    *   'Content-Type': null,
    * },
    */
    body
  }
);
```

**CORRECT**

```js
fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {},
   body
});

// or delete headers['Content-Type'] if necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

I also bumped into this and needed to remove the multipart header declaration. Full example:

HTML:

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={(e) => {
    if (e?.target?.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      handleImageFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  }}
/>
```

JS:

```js
const handleImageFile = (file) => {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("user_id", 171);
  fd.append("avatar", file);
  fetch("/user/avatar/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: fd,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]")?.getAttribute("content"),
    },
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(" * result", result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn(" * error", err);
    });
};
```

Controller:

```rb
def user_avatar
  user = User.find(user_avatar_params[:user_id])
  user.avatar = user_avatar_params[:avatar]
  user.save!
end

def user_avatar_params
  params.permit(:user_id, :avatar)
end
```