# Rails 6 SPA ActiveStorage Invalid request parameters: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, rails-activestorage

I have been trying without any success to upload a mp3 from a react SPA app to a rails backend.
I'm using active storage with a local storage backend.

Unfortunately, I'm always experiencing a `Invalid request parameters: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` upon upload.

Ruby 2.6.2
Rails 6.0.2.1

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', values.name);
formData.append('text', values.text);
formData.append('transition', values.transition);
formData.append('audio', values.audio[0]);

// Store state
const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/states/${state.id}`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  },
  body: formData
});
```

Controller:

```rb
  # PATCH/PUT /states/1
  def update
    if @state.update state_params
      render json: { state: @state }
    else
      render json: @state.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def state_params
      params.require(:state).permit(
        :name, 
        :content, 
        :text, 
        :transition, 
        :left, 
        :top, 
        :feature_id,
        audio: {}
      )
    end
```

Model:

```rb
class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :audio
end
```

Request headers:

```
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,fr-FR;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8000/surveys/1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Content-Length: 4705407
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

error stack:

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/states/37" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-26 13:08:25 +0100

ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):

rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:86:in `normalize_params'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:71:in `block in parse_nested_query'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:68:in `each'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:68:in `parse_nested_query'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/request.rb:590:in `parse_query'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/request.rb:454:in `POST'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:382:in `block (2 levels) in POST'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:109:in `block in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:109:in `fetch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:109:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:381:in `block in POST'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:380:in `POST'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:43:in `filtered_parameters'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:23:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
rack-utf8_sanitizer (1.6.0) lib/rack/utf8_sanitizer.rb:22:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.3) lib/rack/cors.rb:95:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

> To upload files using `fetch` and `FormData`
>   you must not set `Content-Type` header.

From: https://muffinman.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/